# How can I use wsman on Linux without passing passwords in plaintext?

Tags: linux, wsman, openwsman

I'm using [libwsman/wsmancli](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/4139.web-services-management-wsman-linux-client-installation-setup) and libcurl4-32bit to run wsman commands from a linux box against the iDracs of some Dell boxes I have. The problem I'm running into is authentication requires plaintext password and username. This is fine if I use it from the commandline; however, I'm using the dell python wrapper (basically just a wrapper for subprocess) execute the commands in a script I've written. So, every instance where I run a command, I need to pass my password in plaintext.. Is there a way around this? The only alternative I can think of is to add a less-privileged user to each of the iDracs; but that doesn't resolve the underlying issue..

Comment: How about reading the username/password from a file?

Comment: That is actually a viable option; but I would still prefer to use certs or something if possible..